# Solve $x'=1+x^2$. Using Peano theorem determine for which $t$ solution exists and on what is its maximal interval.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Using Peano theorem determine for which $t$ solution exists and on what is its maximal interval.

So we have $x'=1+x^2$ and $x(0)=0$

It is easy to find out that solution is $x=\tan t$

So $f(x,t)=\frac{1}{\cos^2t}$

So we see that $f$ is continuous on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. $|x|$ has not upper bound on this interval.
Is it everything needed to conclude that solutions exist on aforementioned interval and that it is maximal?

Comment: No, $f(x,t)=1+x^2$ in this problem setting. Which Peano theorem do you refer to? The existence theorem for continuous ODE?

Comment: Yeah, this one.

Comment: I think I understand it now. If nobody posts solution until tommorow, I will do it.

Comment: Of course your computations and the maximal interval are correct, however it is not clear what role the theorem would serve. The more typical task is for $f(x,t)=t^2+x^2$ where no symbolic solution is available and one can ask for the largest provable domain of a solution.